# What does details mean in the definition of detailed

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, vocabulary

Detailed (adjective) means

having too many details

example: a detailed answer

What does this details mean in the definition of the adjective Detailed?

Since the noun detail has two meanings:

1.an individual fact or item

2.a minor, less significant point

In my interpretation

## #1 and #2 mean the same thing as

When someone alleges rape, the interrogator may ask for lots of "details" such what time was it, what were you wearing, what colour was the attacker's shoes, how did you get home afterwards, etc.

These details could be seen as "mere details" compared with the main fact, but those details could be extremely important as evidence of truthfulness or in identifying the actual attacker.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking "***details***" are small pieces of information that may ultimately prove very important, thus the expression

> **The Devil's in the details**

meaning, the smaller, finer points may cause problems.

> P1: If you want to drive to New York City, you'd better fill your gas tank.
>   P2: Oh, that's just a detail.

It's important to have gas, but it is easily overcome by stopping at a petrol station.

Comment: so if something is detailed . like, a detailed answer. it'll have every individual detail of that particular subject. Whether it's less significant or more.

Comment: Correct, it will have lots of pieces of information which should be *relevant*  to the main point.